# Collating Variables to an Array

Tags: arrays, powershell, wildcard

I wish to collate variables to an array.
I have 10 variables directories, all with the same prefix, similar to dir1, dir2 etc.
Can I simply assign all these to an array using a wildcard like so?

```
$all_dirs = $dir*
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Get-Variable` cmdlet:

```
$all_dirs = Get-Variable -Name dir* -ValueOnly
```

A better approach to variable management is to start with an array or hashtable instead.